# Not possible to have accents in tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, user-interface

I think that if we want to have our tags in French by default, it would be preferable to be able to have accented characters. It's apparently not the case at the moment.

Also - I'm not sure how Lucent handles accents in full-text search. Is that likely to be a problem?

Comment: For reference, here's [the feature request on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102828/tags-cannot-have-accented-characters).

Comment: FWIW, there's [an older request on MSO that you might want to check out...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/implement-tag-diacritics-with-automatic-synonyms) it takes into account some of the issues that could arise if this was implemented.

Comment: update: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags

Comment: [meta-tag:status-buggy] — [Database inconsistencies after tag-merge operations involving non-ASCII characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224158/database-inconsistencies-after-tag-merge-operations-involving-non-ascii-characte). But [there is hope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173294/tags-dont-want-to-play-with-s/173320#comment755755_173320)!

Answer (score 5):

With the addition of non-English sites, localization is becoming a an increasing priority on Stack Exchange. But it's not as simple as just piecing in accent support here and there. The localization of Stack Exchange will likely be done as a comprehensive effort to make sure it isn't half supported piecemeal.

[**The State of Localization**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation/82229#82229)

We have your [feature request] and we hear you. We are committed to supporting sites in other languages. We have been able to launch sites like the French Language SE without delay, but there have been a few compromises to fit these non-English subject into the predominantly English-speaking system.

I know this is not ideal; It's all a bit of a compromise in lieu of saying "Sorry you cannot create proposals for non-English sites until we have a proper localization interface."

Comment: So, in short: the state of localization is the same as it was 5 months ago. At least that's information, if somewhat depressing :)

Comment: I still find it comforting somewhat. Hopefully when it arrives, we'll be able to change all tags in a smooth way.

Comment: Robert, I do feel that accents in tags doesn't really count as localization - we're not talking about translating the interface or making it multilingual. Tags are 'user content': all we need is that the accents don't get 'eaten'. That's not to say that it's (necessarily) technically trivial, but I'm not seeing a reason to wait for everything to be done before implementing that (unless it *is* effectively a question of database collation, in which case... good luck!)

Comment: Could we have some new update? Is it currently possible to allow the few accentuated letters we need in tags?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I was under the impression that non-Latin characters has been supported in tags for quite some time. See http://russian.stackexchange.com/tags and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/add-non-latin-character-set-support-for-tags/135955#135955. Let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: It isn't the case currently.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Non-Latin characters in tags should be enabled shortly, assuming it hasn't already (waiting for the next build).

Answer (score 4):

I filed a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102828/tags-cannot-have-accented-characters) on the main Meta. Unfortunately, I got no “official” feedback from any moderator or staff (yet). I don't know exactly how we demonstrate our (nascent) community’s support for this much-needed feature.

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at the big notice box at the top of the (ready to launch) [Chinese Emigration](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36960/chinese-emigration) proposal, it seems that things are moving their way. Let's hope for the best, if the stack exchange team will not forget about us, this feature might be available soon :-)

Notice also that non-ascii characters in tags are already supported on the [Russian L&U](https://russian.stackexchange.com/). It might be time to revive this question, but bounties are not available on meta, a pity.

Comment: I've been told that bounties on [meta.so] are completely irrelevant for what the community team or dev team might do, so don't worry about bounties. The primary way to promote a feature request is to have a good case for it and to get moderators to nag the community team about it.

Answer (score 1):

We seem to have forgotten to record it on meta, but accented tag names have been possible for several months now.

We've renamed all the existing tags that lacked accents and kept the unaccented name as a synonym (for people who can't type accented letters easily). Given our policy of [French tag names with English synonyms](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/should-question-tags-be-in-english-or-french-or-both), this means that tags normally have one or two synonyms, e.g. [étymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tymologie) has the synonyms [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie) and [etymology](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology).

If you see or create a tag that lacks the desired synonyms or is misspelled, please contact a moderator in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) or ask on this meta site.

---

Il est désormais possible (depuis quelques mois en fait) d'inclure des lettres accentuées dans les noms d'étiquettes. Les étiquettes existantes ont été renommées.

Nous conservons le nom sans accent comme synonyme, pour faciliter la vie des gens qui ne peuvent pas taper des lettres accentuées facilement. Vu notre règle suivant laquelle [les noms d'étiquettes sont en principe français avec la traduction anglaise comme synonyme](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/should-question-tags-be-in-english-or-french-or-both), les étiquettes ont donc normalement un ou deux synonymes, par exemple [étymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tymologie) a les synonymes [etymologie](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymologie) et [etymology](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)

Si vous voyez ou vous créez une étiquette mal orthographiée ou à laquelle il manque les synonymes attendus, merci de contacter les modérateurs dans le [salon de clavargage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) ou de demander sur le site méta.