# Learning resources for beginners

Tags: discussion, resources

Should we have a list of learning resources for those who are new to French?  As a meta (wiki) post, I would assume.

[Here is an example of a list](https://plus.google.com/112883523226102191623/posts/2x97mxTS3Kd) of French language resources I have been compiling on Google+. We can start with these on a wiki here or similar if there is an interest in it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Good idea, and nice list. You should add a link to the CNRTL site : http://www.cnrtl.fr/

Comment: I have started one here too: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar

Answer (score 8):

A meta wiki post is what is done on EL&U. I would prefer to do it as a wiki post on the main site, for a few reasons:

1. People who don't know the workings of SE don't search for these things on the Meta, just on the main site.
2. Meta should be English only (as per [this](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/can-stack-exchange-employees-understand-french/70#70)), and we want our list to be in both languages.

I'd like to have others’ thoughts on this proposal.

Comment: I'm not SUPER certain that the Q&A format is better than sticking it in the faq, but it's certainly going to be easier to maintain. (I'd quite like the idea of the Q&A eventually stabilising and getting moved into the faq). That said, I agree with everything you say here.

Comment: A crash course in IPA would be a good thing too :)

Comment: I'm not sure about how much `2.` still stands, but is this becoming a feature request, now that a consensus seems to be gathered ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a great idea. Questions like *What's the IPA for [a word] ?* could be avoided that way.

But it should be very visible for visitors. Maybe like a "stay at top" community wiki or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mind having such a wiki. I saw something similar on the Spanish meta site. However on the Spanish site they used this as an excuse to disallow all resource requests on the main site.

So as long as we could still make specific resource requests I wouldn't see a problem with this.